# Palindrome Coding issue

Tags: python, string, palindrome

Writing a program:

1. Input string from the user
2. print out whether this string is a palindrome or not

Also, I found a few other codes online but want to work with this code only.m Please let me know the error

```
i = str(input())

for item in i:
  print(item)

  if int(i[item]) == int(i[-item]):
    print('yes')
  else:
    print('no')
```

Comment: Hello! Please format supply your problem and make it not a homework question. Thanks!

Comment: Here it is expected that you inform us about the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `for item in i:` loops through every character in the string, there are several problems with your code line `if int(i[item]) == int(i[-item]):`.  First of all, `item` is going to be a character from your string.  So if the user types "hello", then `i[item]` first looks for `i['h']`.  Since 'h' is a character and not a number, this makes Python think that `i` is a dictionary and not a string, and thus tells Python to look for a dictionary named `i` and return the value where the key is `h`.  That won't work since `i` is your original string, not a dictionary.

It looks like what you meant to do here is compare `i[0]` (the first character in the string) to `i[-1]` (the last character in the string), then `i[1]` to `i[-2]`, and so on. But even you if looped through the position numbers, `i[-item]` doesn't mathematically give you what you want.

Yet another issue here is that you're checking each character one at a time and returning "yes" or "no". What you ultimately want though is to output one simple answer: whether your string is a palindrome or not.

Also, there's no need to put `str()` around `input()`, since `input` returns a string anyway, even if the user enters only numerals.  By the way, even though you're using `i` as your string variable, the usual convention in programming is to use `i` to denote some sort of integer, such as one you're iterating through in a `for` loop.  But that's OK for now.

As some of the other answers have shown, `i[::-1]` is a quick way to return the reverse of a string itself.  So if you're OK with seeing the output return `True` if the string is a palindrome and `False` if it isn't, then here's an extremely simple way to do it:

```
i = input()
print(i == i[::-1])
```

If the string `i` is identical to itself reversed, then `i == i[::-1]` returns `True`.  If not, it returns `False`.  The `print` statement then prints whichever the answer is.

However, if you really do want to do it the long way, testing character by character in a loop, then here's one way to do it.  You could make a function that takes in a string and does the work:

```
def is_palindrome(mystring):
    # The "//2" here divides by 2 and ignores the remainder.  So if
    # there are an even number of letters, we'll test each pair.  If
    # It's an odd number, then we don't care about the middle character
    # anyway.  Compare [0] to [-1], then [1] to [-2], [2] to [-3], and so on.
    for position in range(0, len(mystring)//2):
        # If we've found a mismatched pair of letters, then we can
        # stop looking; we know it's not a palindrome.
        if mystring[position] != mystring[(-1 * position) - 1]:
            print("This is NOT a palindrome")
            return  # This breaks you out of the entire function.

    # If we've gotten this far, then the word must be a palindrome.
    print("This is a palindrome")


# Here's where we run the command to input the string, and run the function
mystring = input("Enter your string: ")
is_palindrome(mystring)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Great Explanation!

Comment: You're welcome!  Please consider selecting my answer as the definitive "chosen" answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a String slice (The `i[::-1]` will reverse the string):

```
i = input()

if i == i[::-1]:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

This will take the input from the user and compare it against the same input in reverse.

Comment: Hello! Please make your code syntactically valid and explain what your code does. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
word="TOT"
i=word[::-1]
if i==word:
    print("palandrom")
```